# Verifying in-app purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, licensing, windows-store, receipt

I'm building a Windows Store app that provides in-app purchases. I do not understand from the available documentation how does this work with multiple installations or devices. I want my users to be able to use the IAPs with multiple installations on different devices (purchase once, use on any device).

Here is an excerpt from [Using receipts to verify purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx):

> In some situations, you may need to verify that a user purchased your
>   app, or has made in-app content purchases. For example, imagine a game
>   that offers downloaded content. If the user who purchased the game
>   content wants to play it on a different Windows 8 device, you need to
>   verify that the user already owns the content.

And also from [Protecting your Windows Store app from unauthorized use](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8b3cf68d-897d-4a47-ace0-2c42355bf688/protecting-your-windows-store-app-from-unauthorized-use?forum=windowsstore):

> To prevent users from employing this strategy to illegally use your
>   apps, we have a receipt feature that allows you to validate a user’s
>   access to your app and service. Your app is able to obtain a signed
>   receipt for any app-related transaction made through the Windows
>   Store, such as the initial purchase of the app and any in-app
>   purchases. Your app can then use this info to determine what services
>   or features it can access for that user. [...] The ID of each receipt
>   element is unique per user (and device) and you can validate it on
>   your server to confirm that the transaction is legitimate for that
>   user and not a fraudulent transaction. This is especially valuable
>   when your app has its own authentication mechanism because it allows
>   you to validate that each user that appears to have purchased your app
>   is, in fact, a unique customer.

My questions are:

1. When is it necessary to have a back-end to store receipts?
2. When do I check the receipts in the back-end (when the app starts)?
3. The receipt is unique per device. How does this help with multiple devices? I want my users to be able to use the IAPs on multiple devices if they purchased them once.
4. If the receipt is used to validate legitimate transactions, does that mean the info provided by the `CurrentApp` component may not be authentic, but tempered by hacks? If that is so, why should I trust the original receipt in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. XML signature can be checked at the device without any problems, but device can be compromised(in theory) and it's better to check it at your server (I think that example is about some game with online stuff that can be purchased or a magazine app with downloadable content).
2. When the user are trying to use it or fetch the available stuff. At start if it something important for app to work. There is no limitation, but it will take some time and the user should know that app is doing something and not just hang.
3. ID looks like a value that you should store at your back-end (in the user account) and validate it per each DeviceId. However there also ProductId and signature which is enough to check for consistency.
4. Of course it can be compromised. Hacker can replace the certificate check URL and you'll pass the check. This is why they recommend to use back-end and check the certs at your own server (however, your server can be compromised too, in theory ;)

The best way to check receipts:

1. Getting receipt in app.
2. Sending receipt to backend.
3. Checking receipt at backend and allowing user to download paid content or not (if receipt is not valid).